# check number with 4 conditions

Tags: visual-prolog

i am new here and i need some help with my simple code if it possible

in visual prolog i want check the number in 4 cases 
-1 , negative odd
1 , positive odd

-2 , negative even
2 , positive even

i try this one

```
Predicates 
Print.  
Clauses 
Print:- write ("enter number "),nl, readint(X),
        X>0,X mod 2= 0,write("positive ","even"),
        X<0,X mod 2= 0,write("negative ","even") ,

        X>0,X mod 2 <> 0,write("positive ","odd"),
        X<0,X mod 2 <> 0,write("negative ","odd") .

Goal 
Print.
```

any idea to help me with this problem

Comment: Long time since I looked into Visual-Prolog but... should it be `print` instead of `Print`? Also, if you want to use a single clause for the predicate, you will need to use disjunctions in the clause body...

Comment: This is what I study now, and I did not find enough information to help me with it

Comment: Well, I know nothing about Visual Prolog, but in most any other language I written code in, your print statement is a rough way to approach the problem.  Instead, use "if" statements to separate out the four cases and then, depending on the case selected, have a very simple straight forward print . . . each one might just print a constant string.  That kind of code will be much easier to debug.

Comment: @FrankMerrow thank you for your comment appreciate that , in vip (visual prolog) i don't know if we can use if statements so , in one line you can add only two conditions no more that